# Workflows to move list A to B which has restricted permissions in SP13

Tags: list, permissions

I have created a workflow successfully to move contents of list A to list B and delete items in List A. However, I want to restrict List B to Site owners only. And allow members to fill the data in List A and not see the contents in list B. when i did this with full permissions it worked, but as a member the workflow doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: did you try to stop inheritance on List B and remove everybody's permission expect the one you want? then what happed? did workflow copy the items?

Comment: i removed permissions, added members only to list A and site owners for list b.

Comment: do you want to restrict the user in list A as well?

Comment: i want to restrict the user from seeing list B only. But in List A they should only be able to add details into a form. the workflow moves the list items from A to B and deletes A and emails me. Which all worked but when i get a member to do this, the data stays in list A and not move to B

Comment: I am sorry i am little confused, if Workflow moves the items as soon as user added it to list A then what you mean by member to do this is not work?

Comment: Member = fills out form fileds (list A) Then the workflow, send this list to List B and deletes item in List A.

Comment: When I restrict it to MEMBERS only as apposed to SITE OWNERS (i restricted the LIST B to SITE OWNERS ONLY) so mebers can create a entry on list A but then the wworkflow moves this info to List B, so they can no longer see it.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to make that insert into list B as an impersonation step. This used to be an option in 2010 that would allow workflow actions to execute as the user who publishes the workflow.

I'm not very familiar with 2013 yet, but I believe this was moved into a feature that isn't enabled by default called an App Step. See if this article helps you, http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2012/12/20/sharepoint-designer-2013-the-new-app-step/

Comment: Thank you for this, I tried to do this but i have now noticed that SP2010 has copy list item but SP2013 doesnt, What do I do??? do i create one workflow in 2010 (move list a to b) and then add the App step in 2013? rather confusing and not very well thought of?